# How can you pass a dictionary as parameters to solve_ivp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I was having difficulties trying to pass a dictionary as the parameters to Scipy's solve_ivp to solve a system of ODEs given below. The issue is my system has many parameters (more than shown below). For convenience and to avoid making errors changing individual values from a long list e.g [20,8,2,120,-80,...,30], I would like to pass a lookup table of parameters like this dictionary:

```py
def morris_lecar2_defaults():
    return {
        "C_M" : 20,
        "g_K" : 8,
        "g_L" : 2,
        "V_Ca" : 120,
        "V_K" : -80,
        "V_L" : -60,
        "V_1" : -1.2,
        "V_2" : 18,
        "g_Ca" : 4.0,
        "phi" : 1/15,
        "V_3" : 12,
        "V_4" : 17.4,
        "I_ext" : 30,
    }

def morris_lecar2(t, u, p):
    (V, N) = u
    M_inf = 0.5*(1 + np.tanh((V - p["V_1"])/p["V_2"])) # (2)
    N_inf = 0.5*(1 + np.tanh((V - p["V_3"])/p["V_4"])) # (3)
    tau_N = 1/(p["phi"]*np.cosh((V - p["V_3"])/(2*p["V_4"]))) # (4)
    # (1)
    dVdt = (-p["g_L"]*(V - p["V_L"]) - p["g_Ca"]*M_inf*(V - p["V_Ca"]) - p["g_K"]*N*(V - p["V_K"]) + p["I_ext"])/p["C_M"]
    dNdt = (N_inf - N)/tau_N
    return np.array((dVdt, dNdt))
```

The issue is when I pass this to Scipy's solve_ivp routine as the optional args parameter I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 159, in <module>
    sol_2 = solve_ivp(Morris_Lecar2,(0, 1000), (-20, 1, 0.001), args= morris_lecar2_defaults)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\ivp.py", line 542, in solve_ivp
    solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\rk.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.f = self.fun(self.t, self.y)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py", line 138, in fun
    return self.fun_single(t, y)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py", line 20, in fun_wrapped
    return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\ivp.py", line 514, in <lambda>
    fun = lambda t, x, fun=fun: fun(t, x, *args)
TypeError: Morris_Lecar2() argument after * must be an iterable, not function
```

The dictionary is still treated as a function object and despite several attempts to resolve this issue I've had no luck. What is the most pythonic yet user-friendly way to solve this large parameter set problem which satisfies solve_ivp?

Comment: Although I don't know what the function signature is for solve_ivp, why not express it as args=morris_lecar2_defaults(). That way at least you are passing in the result of that function, rather than a pointer to the function. I also read in scipy's documentation that "args must be a tuple of length 3", so not sure if a dict is right...

Comment: You are missing how you are calling `solve_ivp`, EDIT: I see now that it is buried in the stack trace.  It would be a more readable question if you provided it separately

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), it appears `args` should be a `tuple`. So, try this:

```py
sol_2 = solve_ivp(
    Morris_Lecar2, (0, 1000), (-20, 1, 0.001), args=(morris_lecar2_defaults(),)
)
```

Note that the trailing comma here `args=(morris_lecar2_defaults(),)` is *required*. Also, note that I'm calling the `morris_lecar2_defaults()` function.

It would make more sense to make `morris_lecar2_defaults` a `dict`, and then just pass that as a single item `tuple`:

```py
morris_lecar2_defaults = {
    "C_M": 20,
    "g_K": 8,
    "g_L": 2,
    "V_Ca": 120,
    "V_K": -80,
    "V_L": -60,
    "V_1": -1.2,
    "V_2": 18,
    "g_Ca": 4.0,
    "phi": 1 / 15,
    "V_3": 12,
    "V_4": 17.4,
    "I_ext": 30,
}

sol_2 = solve_ivp(
    Morris_Lecar2, (0, 1000), (-20, 1, 0.001), args=(morris_lecar2_defaults,)
)
```

Also, shouldn't `morris_lecar2` be lowercase since the function definition is lowercase?

So:

```py
morris_lecar2_defaults = {
    "C_M": 20,
    "g_K": 8,
    "g_L": 2,
    "V_Ca": 120,
    "V_K": -80,
    "V_L": -60,
    "V_1": -1.2,
    "V_2": 18,
    "g_Ca": 4.0,
    "phi": 1 / 15,
    "V_3": 12,
    "V_4": 17.4,
    "I_ext": 30,
}

sol_2 = solve_ivp(
    morris_lecar2, (0, 1000), (-20, 1, 0.001), args=(morris_lecar2_defaults,)
)
```